# setTimeout in loop in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to implement logic for smart search. I am using below code in `onChangeText` on `TextInput`

```
 clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = 0
        this.timeout = this.timer(text);
```

Here i am clearing last `timeOut` and setting new one in `timer` method

```
timer = (searchText) => {
        const { selectedFilter } = this.state

        setTimeout(function () {
            //Hit Api
            console.log("new instance" + selectedFilter)


        }, 2000);
    }
```

Above code is working fine but there is one issue, previous listener is not getting cleared. so i am getting console multiple time. Please suggest me what i am doing wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this library. https://github.com/fractaltech/react-native-timer It will help you

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: yes its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return the value returned by the setTimeout call, like this:

```
timer = (searchText) => {
    const { selectedFilter } = this.state

    return setTimeout(function () {
        //Hit Api
        console.log("new instance" + selectedFilter)
    }, 2000);
}
```

Also, you don't need to do `this.timeout = 0` just before `this.timeout = this.timer(text);`